# Using parse-xml to convert text to node in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-3.0

I am working with XML output from an Access database, where the text within some of the nodes need to be converted to nodes themselves through XSLT which will then be run through Adobe FrameMaker to create a publication. Looking online, I have seen numerous references to an XSLT function I should have available called parse-xml (Framemaker's XSLT can use Saxon 9.8), which should allow me to do what I am trying to do. I haven't found a single example of this function being used, and I am still novice enough with XSLT that I can't quite imagine the correct construction of the code. In addition, if you know of a web based XSLT 3.0 tester that would be a great help. I have been using XSLtransform.net which was fantastic, but it doesn't support XSLT 3.0 (at least through Saxon 9.8 like Framemaker does).

My XML I need to convert:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-09-26T10:37:15">
<TEQuery>
<IntID>PR090F</IntID>
<TEName>Exempt Lease From Taxable Owner</TEName>
<Description>

&lt;div&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;&amp;nbsp;Leased properties that qualify for this exemption are reported under one of the following expenditures: &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;ul&gt;
 &lt;ul&gt;
  &lt;ul&gt;
   &lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;ul&gt;
     &lt;ul&gt;
      &lt;ul&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR001F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR007F,&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR079F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR083F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR085F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR086F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;/ul&gt;
     &lt;/ul&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;
   &lt;/ul&gt;
  &lt;/ul&gt;
 &lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
</Description>
<TaxSort>2</TaxSort>
</TEQuery>
</dataroot>
```

My desired output is as follows:

```xml
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
          generated="2023-09-26T10:37:15">
  
   <TaxExpenditure id="PR090F" TAXSORT="2">Exempt Lease From Taxable Owner
      <Description>
&lt;div&gt;&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;&amp;nbsp;Leased properties that qualify for this exemption are reported under one of the following expenditures: &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
<unorderedlist>
       <listitem>;&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR001F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
       <listitem>;&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR007F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
       <listitem>&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR079F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
       <listitem>&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR083F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
       <listitem>&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR085F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
       <listitem>&lt;font face="Times New Roman" color=black&gt;PR086F, &lt;/font&gt;</listitem>
   </unorderedlist>
   </TaxExpenditure>
</dataroot>
```

This is my current XSL code, that works to do everything so far other than converting the list strings into nodes, but I am 100% lost on next steps with the parse-xml function, whether it should reside in an xsl:template statement or something else, etc. Any help that could be provided in removing the "<font face..." and "<div>" portions of the text through xslt would also be appreciated, though I suspect I may need to do this later in the process outside of xslt or to convert those also to nodes before dropping them.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TEQuery">
    <TaxExpenditure>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="IntID"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="TAXSORT" select="TaxSort"/>
      <xsl:value-of select = "TEName"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </TaxExpenditure>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="IntID"/>
<xsl:template match="TaxSort"/>
<xsl:template match="TEName"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The content of the `Description` contains some markup that is not proper XML (i.e. the `&lt;div&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black` will yield an error as the `color` attribute value has no quote delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have pointed out in a comment, the content of the `Description` element is not well-formed according to XML rules, as there are, at least, some attribute values not properly delimited by quote characters.

Therefore neither `parse-xml` nor `parse-xml-fragment` will be able to parse that content successfully.

Either check whether your version/edition of Saxon in Framemaker is a commercial one (i.e. PE or EE), then you can use (depending the exact version) the extension function `saxon:parse-html` https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/saxon/parse-html.html or the new XPath 4 `fn:parse-html`.

On the other hand, there is is a nice little HTML tag soup parser implementation done in pure XSLT 2, namely David Carlisle's https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl, which you can import and then use like (assuming a namespace declaration `xmlns:dc="data:,dpc"`) e.g.

```
<xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="Description">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:htmlparse(., '', true())"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then you basically have the HTML as XDM nodes (e.g. `div`, `font`, `ul`, `li` element nodes) and you can add templates to transform them e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="li">
  <listitem>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </listitem>
</xsl:template>
```

It is not quite clear if you really want some result elements like `listitem` but then inside again escaped markup; you could serialize the nodes of course with `fn:serialize` although that will then after having parsed them and with the serialization XSLT allows and Saxon implements (e.g. probably with quotes around attribute values), meaning it is not possible to preserve the original escaped markup.

As for fiddling with XSLT 3 in the browser, there is https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/ using SaxonJS (2.5 currently) ([your sample and my XSLT suggestion](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%223.0%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22data%3A%2Cdpc%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20omit-xml-declaration%3D%22yes%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Aimport%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fdavidcarlisle%2Fweb-xslt%2Fmain%2Fhtmlparse%2Fhtmlparse.xsl%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22TEQuery%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTaxExpenditure%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22id%22%20select%3D%22IntID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22TAXSORT%22%20select%3D%22TaxSort%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%20%3D%20%22TEName%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FTaxExpenditure%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Description%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22dc%3Ahtmlparse%28.%2C%20%27%27%2C%20true%28%29%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22li%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Clistitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Flistitem%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22ul%5Bul%5D%20%7C%20font%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22ul%5Bnot%28ul%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CunorderedList%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FunorderedList%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22IntID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22TaxSort%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22TEName%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cdataroot%20xmlns%3Aod%3D%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aofficedata%22%20generated%3D%222023-09-26T10%3A37%3A15%22%3E%0D%0A%3CTEQuery%3E%0D%0A%3CIntID%3EPR090F%3C%2FIntID%3E%0D%0A%3CTEName%3EExempt%20Lease%20From%20Taxable%20Owner%3C%2FTEName%3E%0D%0A%3CDescription%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%26lt%3Bdiv%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3B%26amp%3Bnbsp%3BLeased%20properties%20that%20qualify%20for%20this%20exemption%20are%20reported%20under%20one%20of%20the%20following%20expenditures%3A%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bul%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR001F%2C%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR007F%2C%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR079F%2C%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR083F%2C%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR085F%2C%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3Bli%26gt%3B%26lt%3Bfont%20face%3D%26quot%3BTimes%20New%20Roman%26quot%3B%20color%3Dblack%26gt%3BPR086F%2C%20%26lt%3B%2Ffont%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fli%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%20%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%26lt%3B%2Ful%26gt%3B%0D%0A%3C%2FDescription%3E%0D%0A%3CTaxSort%3E2%3C%2FTaxSort%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FTEQuery%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdataroot%3E%0D%0A&input-type=XML)) and then I have Saxon 10 in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ and various Saxon versions in https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/.

Keep in mind that https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ allows you to store your fiddles in a db but you then share them with the web, so make sure you don't save anything with private input data or code you want to keep private.

Comment: Hi @martin-honnen, I really appreciate your comment and links to the various resources. I have a variation of the original question here that I was hoping to ask. If necessary, I can post this as a separate question. If I were to change the above text only to replace PR001F with &amp;lt;idref&amp;gt;PR001F&amp;lt;/idref&amp;gt; would there be a way to use the html parser to convert this into an idref element? My Access database is spitting out the "<" and ">" this way and it is not working with the above code from David Carlisle.

Comment: In addition, FrameMaker uses Saxon Enterprise Edition 9.8.3, so if parse-html would work better for this particular addition to the problem I would love to see how that would be implemented.

Comment: @MadeFrame, please post that new question as a separate question on its own, will all the details. As for using `saxon:parse-html`, perhaps also try that on your own based on the existing samples and the documentation https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/functions/saxon/parse-html.html, if you can't get it to work ask a new question detailing what you tried and how it failed to do the job. In the end it is just another function to call and some templates to be used to process the nodes the function returns. In contrast to the code I posted it might put HTML elements in the XHTML ns.