# XSLT string to node conversion and disable-output-escaping

Tags: xml, xslt, html-parsing

I am exporting an Access database to XML, then need to transform the XML to prepare the data for Framemaker to create a publication. In the process, I need to create crossreferences within the text of the Access output. At the moment, my approach is to insert <idref>some text</idref>, but when exporting to XML, this turns into &amp;lt;some text&amp;gt;, and because of this the html parser that I am using is not converting the text into a node like I would like it to. I have Saxon EE 9.8.3, but haven't tested the html-parse because a solution provided in a previous question was able to resolve my initial issues with parsing. ([Using parse-xml to convert text to node in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189695/using-parse-xml-to-convert-text-to-node-in-xml/77189866#77189866))

Here is a version of the XML input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-09-29T08:29:47">
<TEQuery>
<IntID>PR090F</IntID>
<TEName>Exempt Lease From Taxable Owner</TEName>
<Description>
&lt;div&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;&amp;nbsp;Leased &amp;lt;idref&amp;gt;PR001F&amp;lt;/idref&amp;gt; properties that qualify for this exemption are reported under one of the following expenditures: &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;ul&gt;
 &lt;ul&gt;
  &lt;ul&gt;
   &lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;ul&gt;
     &lt;ul&gt;
      &lt;ul&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;&amp;lt;idref&amp;gt;PR001F&amp;lt;/idref&amp;gt;, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR007F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR079F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR083F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR085F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR086F, &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Times New Roman&quot; color=black&gt;PR087F, .&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;/ul&gt;
     &lt;/ul&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;
   &lt;/ul&gt;
  &lt;/ul&gt;
 &lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;</Description>
<TaxSort>2</TaxSort>
</TEQuery>
</dataroot>
```

My desired output is:

```xml
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
          generated="2023-09-26T10:37:15">

   <TaxExpenditure id="PR090F" TAXSORT="2">Exempt Lease From Taxable Owner
      <Description>
Leased <idref>PR001F</idref> properties that qualify for this exemption are reported under one of the following expenditures:
<unorderedList>
            <listitem><idref>PR001F</idref>, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR007F, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR079F, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR083F, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR085F, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR086F, </listitem>
            <listitem>PR087F, </listitem>
         </unorderedList>
   </TaxExpenditure>
</dataroot>
```

I actually have a "solution", in that I can use disable-output-escaping, but I have seen elsewhere that is is a more advanced tool, and often it isn't the ideal fix. Is this the best approach to solving my problem?

*Note that I am using David Carlisle's htmlparse which can be used with XSLT 2.0.

Here is the XSLT I am using:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dc="data:,dpc"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="TEQuery">
    <TaxExpenditure>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="IntID"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="TAXSORT" select="TaxSort"/>
      <xsl:value-of select = "TEName"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </TaxExpenditure>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Description">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:htmlparse(., '', true())"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
  <listitem>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping = "yes"   select="."/>
  </listitem>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="idref">
  <idref>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </idref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[ul] | font | div">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[not(ul)]">
  <unorderedList>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </unorderedList>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="IntID"/>
<xsl:template match="TaxSort"/>
<xsl:template match="TEName"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You say "my approach is to insert <idref>some text</idref>", but it's not clear what you are inserting this into, or how. If this ends up getting escaped, it sounds like you are inserting lexical XML as text into a parsed XML tree structure. If you have a parsed tree structure, you should be inserting nodes into it, not lexical XML strings.

Comment: So in the Access database, I need to be able to allow users to add some sort of text that after being converted to XML and then transformed will end up as an xml node. That exact text that I add to a cell in the database and you quoted is then transformed when exported as XML to what is show in my input XML. I think I understand what you are saying about lexical XML vs. nodes but I don't know of a way to get around doing this because of the workflow I have through Access, so I think the goal is to convert that lexical string into a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xslt already produces your expected outcome.
But I see 2 alternatives

It seems like dc:htmlparse can handle all sorts of (invalid) html, so why not call dc:htmlparse again on `<xsl:template match="li">` like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="li">
    <listitem>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:htmlparse(., '', true())"/>
    </listitem>
  </xsl:template>
```

If you are sure it is valid xml you are inserting, you could also use:

```
  <xsl:template match="li">
    <listitem>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(.)"/>
    </listitem>
  </xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**

This xslt will deal with recursive escaped xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dc="data:,dpc" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="TEQuery">
    <TaxExpenditure>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="IntID"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="TAXSORT" select="TaxSort"/>
      <xsl:value-of select = "TEName"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </TaxExpenditure>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- This template does (optional recursively) what you need without the need of matching specific elements-->
  <xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'&lt;')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dc:htmlparse(., '', true())"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ul[ul] | font | div">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ul[not(ul)]">
    <unorderedList>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </unorderedList>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="IntID"/>
  <xsl:template match="TaxSort"/>
  <xsl:template match="TEName"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently I still have so much to learn. I am still not entirely sure why the parse needs to run a second time and doesn't catch and create the nodes the first time when matching Description, but your first solution here works and I prefer using it to the code I had in the question.

Comment: One problem I have now is that if I copy the &amp;lt;idref&amp;gt;PR001F&amp;lt;/idref&amp;gt; and put it in the Description node instead of within the listitem, then this is not converted into a node, but when I have it within the listitem it does convert. What am I missing there?

Comment: Added a complete xslt that probably will solve your changed example